# Boost.Json, Avoiding Dynamic Allocations, how to determine the required size for temp buffers?

Tags: c++, json, boost

just reading [that part](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/input_output.html#json.input_output.parsing.avoiding_dynamic_allocations) of the Boost.Json docs I wondered what determines the sizes of the arrays given in the code?

```cpp
/*  Parse JSON and invoke the handler

    This function parses the JSON specified in `s`
    and invokes the handler, whose signature must
    be equivalent to:

        void( value const& jv );

    The operation is guaranteed not to perform any
    dynamic memory allocations. However, some
    implementation-defined upper limits on the size
    of the input JSON and the size of the resulting
    value are imposed.

    Upon error, an exception is thrown.
*/
template< class Handler >
void do_rpc( string_view s, Handler&& handler )
{
    unsigned char temp[ 4096 ];                 // The parser will use this storage for its temporary needs
    parser p(                                   // Construct a strict parser using the temp buffer and no dynamic memory
        get_null_resource(),                    // The null resource never dynamically allocates memory
        parse_options(),                        // Default constructed parse options allow only standard JSON
        temp );

    unsigned char buf[ 16384 ];                 // Now we need a buffer to hold the actual JSON values
    static_resource mr2( buf );                 // The static resource is monotonic, using only a caller-provided buffer
    p.reset( &mr2 );                            // Use the static resource for producing the value
    p.write( s );                               // Parse the entire string we received from the network client

    // Retrieve the value and invoke the handler with it.
    // The value will use `buf` for storage. The handler
    // must not take ownership, since monotonic resources
    // are inefficient with mutation.
    handler( p.release() );
}
```

- do they depend on something?
- do they depend on the JSON size?
- is there any formula or helper functions?

EDIT:
[there](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__stream_parser.html#json.ref.boost__json__stream_parser.temporary_storage) I found a few words on the topic, but again nothing about the logic for choosing the sizes of a temporary buffer...

Comment: It is arbitrary example code with arbitrary buffer sizes that you are supposed to "carefully specify". It will throw std::bad_alloc if the provided static sizes are insufficient for actual program. But if you specify these correctly then your program can deal with tons of little jsons efficiently.